# UaSerializationException: request exceeds remote max message size: 2434140 > 2097152

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am a rookie, I tried to use the following code for bulk subscription, but something went wrong, how can I solve this problem

```
    OpcUaSubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = opcUaClient.getSubscriptionManager();
    UaSubscription subscription = subscriptionManager.createSubscription(publishInterval).get();
    List<MonitoredItemCreateRequest> itemsToCreate = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Tag tag : tagList) {
        NodeId nodeId = new NodeId(nameSpace, tag.getPath());
        ReadValueId readValueId = new ReadValueId(nodeId, AttributeId.Value.uid(), null, null);
        MonitoringParameters parameters = new MonitoringParameters(
                subscription.nextClientHandle(),    //
                publishInterval,     // 
                null,       // filter, null means use default
                UInteger.valueOf(queueSize),   // queue size
                true        // discard oldest
        );
        MonitoredItemCreateRequest request = new MonitoredItemCreateRequest(readValueId, 
        MonitoringMode.Reporting, parameters);
        itemsToCreate.add(request);
    }
    BiConsumer<UaMonitoredItem, Integer> consumer =(item, id) -> 
    item.setValueConsumer(this::onSubscriptionValue);
   
    List<UaMonitoredItem> items = subscription.createMonitoredItems(
            TimestampsToReturn.Both,
            itemsToCreate,
            consumer
    ).get();

    for (UaMonitoredItem item : items) {
        if (!item.getStatusCode().isGood()) {
            log.error("failed to create item for nodeId={} (status={})",item.getReadValueId().getNodeId(), item.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How many items are you trying to create?

It seems that the resulting message exceeds the limits set by the server you are connecting to. You may need to break your list up and create the items in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the library that you use, but one of the previous steps for a OPC UA client to connect to a server is to negotiate the maximum size of the buffers, the message total size and the max number or chunks a message can be sent, this process is called by the OPC UA documentation as "Handshake".

If your request is too long it should be split and sent in several chunks according to the limits previously negotiated with the server.

And the server will probably also reply in several chunks, all that has to be considered in the programming of an OPC UA client.